# How to replace LinearLayout with a layout that does not restrict element position in my code?

Tags: java, android

I have been experimenting with this code for a college project. The code uses "LinearLayout" which restricts me from freely moving my elements in the xml design editor so any changes that i make with it are overwritten by the linear layout in java. How could i reform this code?

class: MainActivity.java:

```
package com.android.audiorecordtest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
    private static final int REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION = 200;
    private static String fileName = null;

    private RecordButton recordButton = null;
    private MediaRecorder recorder = null;

    private PlayButton   playButton = null;
    private MediaPlayer   player = null;

    // Requesting permission to RECORD_AUDIO
    private boolean permissionToRecordAccepted = false;
    private String [] permissions = {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION:
                permissionToRecordAccepted  = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                break;
        }
        if (!permissionToRecordAccepted ) finish();
    }

    private void onRecord(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startRecording();
        } else {
            stopRecording();
        }
    }

    private void onPlay(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startPlaying();
        } else {
            stopPlaying();
        }
    }

    private void startPlaying() {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            player.setDataSource(fileName);
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

        recorder.start();
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
    }

    class RecordButton extends Button {
        boolean mStartRecording = true;

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onRecord(mStartRecording);
            if (mStartRecording) {
                setText("Stop recording");
            } else {
                setText("Start recording");
            }
            mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
        }
    };

        public RecordButton(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setText("Start recording");
            setOnClickListener(clicker);
        }
    }

    class PlayButton extends Button {
        boolean mStartPlaying = true;

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onPlay(mStartPlaying);
                if (mStartPlaying) {
                    setText("Stop playing");
                } else {
                    setText("Start playing");
                }
                mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;
            }
        };

        public PlayButton(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setText("Start playing");
            setOnClickListener(clicker);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        // Record to the external cache directory for visibility
        fileName = getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
        fileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        recordButton = new RecordButton(this);
        ll.addView(recordButton,
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0));
        playButton = new PlayButton(this);
        ll.addView(playButton,
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0));
        setContentView(ll);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (recorder != null) {
            recorder.release();
            recorder = null;
        }

        if (player != null) {
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the XML code, basically auto-generated. Whatever changes are made are not active in the app because of the way java code is written and this is the problem.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```

This is a required permission added in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

I basically want to replace "LinearLayout" with something that does not restrict me from using XML while retaining all the code's functionality.

Comment: If you are using both xml as well as java code to create layout, then as you said, java one will overwrite the xml layout

Comment: @Gregory Could you please add your xml code in question also? So we can help you more.

Comment: Basically, my xml code is nonexistent, just the ordinary lines Android Studio creates automatically. The problem is, i need to replace the java code with xml. I comment out the lines except for "recordButton" and "playButton" while i also drag & drop buttons with the same id name on the xml design screen, but when i launch the app the buttons don't even exist. I would have posted more of the code and more details but the site limits me... Help?

Comment: I modified the code, it is the entire script file now.

Answer (score 0):

Set Orientation in `LinearLayout` , `Vertical` or `Horizontal`.

```
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the orientation to your LinearLayout. You can try the code below. Also, you should try to use XML to design your layout, until your layout is not very dynamic.

```
 layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayoute instead of LinearLayout  in XML.

Answer (score 0):

Below line is replacing your xml code at runtime.

```
setContentView(ll)
```

So you need to set just your xml file content like.

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_file_name);
```

Buttons which you are creating in java file. You don't have to do this. Just add the buttons to xml file and set that xml file contents like above and Implement the `OnClickListener` in java file and `setOnClickListener` to those buttons also add the respective functionality to those button  at `onClick` event.

Comment: Hello. Even though i understand what you are saying, i am just too new with this to implement on my own and keep the code fully functional. Would you be kind enough to modify the code for me if i provided the entire script? it is about 190 lines (blanks included) and it is easy to read.

Comment: Yes, just add whole script. We will try to fix it.

Comment: I added everything, take your time :)

Comment: Anything new mate?

Comment: Ok i added everything, even a needed change for the manifest file. With copy-pasting of the entire java and xml files, along with the permission addition in the manifest file it can be built and function on a physical device (emulators don't transmit sound so it has to be a physical device). It is a sound recorder / sound playback app that stores audio in external cache. There are two buttons at the top that cannot be moved because xml changes have no effect. If we can have the same code functionality while able to customize design with XML would be awesome...